# AngularJS edit progress bar as html slider

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an bootstrap progress bar and I would like to be able to edit the value with mouse click. Same way as you can edit it for html range slider

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
```

so I would like to have the same control of progress bar with mouse clicks

Comment: develop a custom directive

Comment: thanks I have used bootstrap angularjs directive and created my own handling in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok actually it was much easier then I thought in the end. I have used bootstrap angular directive for progressBar and handled onClick event.

controller:

```
  $ctrl.trackProgress = function(event) { 
      var fullProgressBarWidth = $(event.currentTarget).width();
      $ctrl.progressBarValue = event.offsetX / fullProgressBarWidth * 100;        
  };
```

template:

```
<div class="progress" ng-click="$ctrl.trackProgress($event)">
  <uib-progressbar value="$ctrl.progressBarValue">{{$ctrl.progressBarValue}}</uib-progressbar>
</div>
```